# How to center (horizontal and vertical) text along an textPath inside an arc using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, text, svg, path, d3.js

After playing a while with d3.js and looking at a lot of examples, I was able to draw multiple arcs. Each one starting and ending at an specific degree and and given radius.

```
var dataset = {
    "2":[{"degree1":0,                 "degree2":1.5707963267949,
          "label":"Sample Text Test"},    
         {"degree1":1.5707963267949,   "degree2":3.1415926535898,
          "label":"Lorem ipsum sample text"},
         {"degree1":3.1415926535898,   "degree2":4.7123889803847,
          "label":"Sample Text Text"},
         {"degree1":4.7123889803847,   "degree2":6.2831853071796,
          "label":"Lorem ipsum"}],
    "1":[{"degree1":0,                 "degree2":3.1415926535898,
          "label":"Sample"},
         {"degree1":3.1415926535898,   "degree2":6.2831853071796,
          "label":"Text"}],
    "0":[{"degree1":0,                 "degree2":6.2831853071796,
          "label":""}]
    },
    width   = 450,
    height  = 450,
    radius  = 75;

// Helper methods
var innerRadius = function(d, i, j) {
    return 1 + radius * j;
};

var outerRadius = function(d, i, j) {
    return radius * (j + 1);
};

var startAngle = function(d, i, j) {
    return d.data.degree1;
};

var endAngle = function(d, i, j) {
    return d.data.degree2;
};

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius)
    .startAngle(startAngle)
    .endAngle(endAngle);

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width >> 1) + ',' + (height >> 1) + ')');

var level = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(function(d) {
        return d3.values(dataset);
    })
    .enter()
    .append('g');

var entry = level.selectAll('g')
    .data(function(d, i) {
        return pie(d);
    })
    .enter()
    .append('g');

entry.append('path')
    .attr('fill', '#aaa')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .attr('id', function(d, i, j) {
        return 'arc' + i + '-' + j;
    });

var label = entry.append('text')
    .style('font-size', '20px')
    .attr('dx', function(d, i, j) {
        return Math.round((d.data.degree2 - d.data.degree1) * 180 / Math.PI);
    })
    .attr('dy', function(d, i, j) {
        return ((radius * (j + 1)) - (1 + radius * j)) >> 1;
    });


label.append('textPath')
    .attr('xlink:href', function(d, i, j) {
        return '#arc' + i + '-' + j;
    })
    .style('fill', '#000')
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.label;
    });
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/3FP6P/2/ :

[image]

But some problem still exists:

1. How to center (horizonal und vertical) an text along an textpath of an any length inside an arc described by innerRadius, outerRadius, startAngle and endAngle?
2. The text occurs sometimes bold, sometimes not. Why?
3. The character spacing does not appear to be the same as if it is written inside a . Some letters stick more together as other ones. Why?
4. The letters are not located directly on the path. Some seem to have a little slip up or down. Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Vertical alignment**

You can use another arc with radius `(innerRadius + outerRadius) / 2` and use it as the `textPath` for the labels.

Note that even if you set the `innerRadius == outerRadius`, D3 will draw an path which moves clockwise and then anti-clockwise to doubles over itself. This becomes important while trying to figure out the *horizontal* centre of the path: it is at the `25%` and `75%` points while `0%` and `50%` points lie on the two tips of the arc.

**Horizontal alignment**

Use `text-anchor: middle` on the text element and set `startOffset` to `25%` (or `75%`) on the `textPath`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3FP6P/3/).

This is a more robust way than calculating the `dx` and `dy` by hand.

You should try out Lars's suggestions to further improve the quality and centring of the text, e.g. you might want to set `text-rendering` to `optimizeLegibility` and play with the baseline a bit.

Comment: You probably meant `startOffset`, not `offsetStart`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TextPathElementStartOffsetAttribute.

Answer (score 5):

Issues 2-4 are because of the font rendering. In my browser, the spacing and character size etc is consistent. You can try playing around with the [`text-rendering` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-rendering) to improve things.

To get the text centred, you will need to set the [`alignment-baseline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline) and/or [`dominant-baseline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline) attributes.

If this still doesn't give you the results you're looking for, try decreasing the font size. This may help because a slight rotation of a character will be less visible.

Comment: vertically alignment use `alignment-baseline` works for me.