# How to place the text on center of path in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating paths between the nodes and place the text between the paths. but it shows at node not on path. I have using following code for d3js

```
    var pathGroup  = svg.append("g");

            var path = pathGroup.selectAll("path")
            .data(links)
            .enter().append("svg:path")
            .attr('id', function(d){ return d.source.name})
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })


var distance = pathGroup.selectAll('distance')//.append('svg:text')
                .data(links).enter().append('svg:text')
                .attr('class', 'distance')//.call(force.drag)//.attr('text-anchor','middle')
                .attr('dy','-30')



        var textPath = distance.append('svg:textPath')
                .attr('xlink:href', function(d){ return '#'+d.source.name})
                .attr('startoffset','50%')
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.distance
                })
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447106/how-to-center-horizontal-and-vertical-text-along-an-textpath-inside-an-arc-usi

Comment: I referred that answers also but i can't do in multi paths dynamically. Here i am using straight line between the nodes